# assigning unique IDs in jquery

Tags: jquery

Hey im trying to assign a unique ID number to each of my form elements

heres the fiddle im working on http://jsfiddle.net/d0okie0612/22cTn/

heres the outputted HTML

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="top_form">
    <form>
      Street: <input class="street" name="[][street]" id="form_element" type="text">               <br><br>
      City: <input class="city" name="[][city]" id="form_element" type="text">
      <select>
        <option value=" ">State</option>
        <option value="ca">CA</option>
        <option value="az">AZ</option>
        <option value="de">DE</option>
       </select>
       Zip: <input name="[][zipcode]" type="text"><br /><br />
     </form>
    </div>
  </div>

    <br />
       <a href="#" id="awsomeButton">+ Add Loction</a>
    <br />
     <br />
   <button id="submit_btn">Submit</button>
```

​

and heres the jquery

```
var tpl = ""
+ "<div id='location_div_<%= id %>'><h1>My Location #<%= id %></h1></div>";

var newId = new Date().getTime();
var template = _.template(tpl);
var compiled = template({id: newId});

var addedForm = "<div id='added_form'>"
+ "<a href='#' class='close_btn'>x</a>"
+ "Street: <input name='[][street]' type='text'>"
+ "<br /><br />"
+ "City: <input name='[][city]' type='text'>"
+ "<select>"
+ "<option value=' '>State</option>"
+ "</select>"
+ "Zip: <input name='[][zipcode]' type='text'>"
+ "</div>"


$('#awsomeButton').on('click', 
function(e){
    $(addedForm).hide().appendTo('form').fadeIn('slow');

});

$('.close_btn').live('click', function(event){
event.preventDefault();
$(this).parents('div#added_form:first').fadeOut('slow', function(){
    $(this).remove();    

});
});
```

so basically i want it so that where it says  `name='[][street]'`

i want to have the unique id number im generating from newID to show up in the [] when i inspect the element.

so for example

first location
`[0]street[0]state` etc

second location 
`[1]street[1]state` etc

Im new to jQuery so if you could edit the fiddle to make that happen or if you could just explain to me like a six year old that would be great.

Thank you 
​

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like this with a replace(regex,newvalue)

```
var x = 0
$('#awsomeButton').on('click', function(e) {
    $(addedForm.replace(/[[]]/g, '[' + (x++) + ']')).hide().appendTo('form').fadeIn('slow');
});
```

Where it will replace the `[]` with `[x]` while auto incrementing the number.

http://jsfiddle.net/HDUvG/

If that's too hard for you to understand, you can do a split/join - it will split into arrays wherever there's a `[]` and rejoin it into a string with brackets around the number `'[' + (x++) + ']'`

```
$(addedForm.split('[]').join('[' + (x++) + ']')).hide().appendTo('form').fadeIn('slow');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ffDEg/

Comment: I defined var x = 0.. so after it uses the x it will automatically add 1 to it.  also `/[[]]/g` is a regex finding all `[]` where `/g` is telling it to find it globally and not just the first instance it comes across

Comment: the problem right now is its only adding it to the added form

Comment: Another way would be to do a loop through each form.. i'll give you an example

Comment: @user1502223 hmm.. so did you want the id as the number inside the bracket?

Comment: yeah i replaced x = 0 with x = newId and that seemed to work but its incrementing and not generating new random ids heres the fiddle you can see the newId generating nubmers in the console http://jsfiddle.net/d0okie0612/22cTn/

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20775/discussion-between-user1502223-and-wirey)

Answer (score 0):

You can assign unique IDs to your form elements in a manner such as this.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var elements = $('form input'),
    i;
    for (i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        elements[i].id = "input-" + i;
    }
});
```

This gives the value/s of "#input-0", "#input-1", etc.

You can verify that this works by testing with an example, such as:

```
$('#input-1').css('background-color', 'red');
```